# Inadvertent multiple posts through jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

This is my first post so I hope I am not violating any rules. I have searched quite extensively, but possibly may have not looked for the correct terms that I am looking to resolve.

At any rate, my problem is this: 
I have a table generated with a list of items, the left-most column has a button when clicked calls an ajax Post and or load function to query the history of the item and list it below the table. This works in its true sense of the expected result, however, reviewing the console through FireBug, subsequent clicks on buttons in the list result in the doubling of posts. ie. 1st click shows 1 console event, 2nd click shows 2 console events, 3rd click shows 4 console events, and so on. this continues until I select a different location and the count resets.

The below is what I see in the console. This presents a problem with timing as each subsequent post takes longer.

> clicking the hist-tag button 5365

```
>GET http://localhost/digipens/query.php?rec_id=5365
```

> clicking the hist-tag button 5365

```
>GET http://localhost/digipens/query.php?rec_id=5365
```

> clicking the hist-tag button 5365

```
>GET http://localhost/digipens/query.php?rec_id=5365
```

> clicking the hist-tag button 5365

```
>GET http://localhost/digipens/query.php?rec_id=5365
```

code:

```
$('.hist-tag').click(function(){

  var ID=$(this).closest('tr').attr('id')

  itemid  = $("#itemid_input_"+ID).val();
  dataString = '?rec_id='+ID;

  $('#item_hist').load('query.php' + dataString); 

});
```

Any ideas or different ways to accomplish the same goal would be excellent.

Thanks!

Comment: What does your html look like before and after your click the button? Hint: the relevant parts would center around the #item_hist elements.

Comment: on the main page the code before and after is just a div.

    
                <div id="item_hist"></div>

as i mentioned in the OP, i do get the expected results ie. a listing of the items history from the desired table, however the unexpected behaviour is the doubling up of posts. if i click 4 different items, the  4th item i click will result in a post that issues 8 times...

Comment: try doing an alert($('#item_hist').length); before your .load and see what you get.

Comment: @Rob - I added the alert and I get "1" for the returned length. However, on each subsequent click of an item, I get "1" in multiple alert windows.

Comment: That means the Answers below are on the right track, your code to bind the click event is being re-run each time you click the button. Either make sure .load is not getting duplicate versions of your javascript, or unbind the click event before you bind it again, so as simple as $('.hist-tag').off('click').click(fun...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your click event is somehow being re-bound on each return.
Perhaps the same script is included in the response from your load call?

Try this:

```
$('.hist-tag').off('click');
$('.hist-tag').on('click', function(){
    var ID=$(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
    itemid=$("#itemid_input_"+ID).val();
    dataString = '?rec_id='+ID;
    $('#item_hist').load('query.php' + dataString);
    return false;  // prevents bubbling the click to the container
});
```

Comment: I selected this as my answer as it provided the quickest resolution for my timeline. Had I the time to rewrite a bunch of code, I would have tried Jeff's answer. I hope this is ok with everyone...

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if you are adding a click handler as a result of your click.  Do you call `$('.hist-tag').click()` after the table updates?  If so, you are adding new click handlers each time, which means the click is handled twice, and then 4 times, and then 8 times, etc.

I can only guess, because I don't see the relevant code here.

If so, the correct solution is to only add your click handler once, and do it via an `.on()` call.  This way, the clicks are handled for current and future elements:

```
$('#mytable').on('click', '.hist-tag', function(){
    var ID=$(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
    itemid=$("#itemid_input_"+ID).val();
    dataString = '?rec_id='+ID;
    $('#item_hist').load('query.php' + dataString);
});
```

This attaches a handler to an element that you know will always exist `#mytable`, or whatever the ID of your table is, and then watches for clicks on children that propagate to the table and filters them on the selector you provide, i.e. `.hist-tag`.

Again, I am guessing, but that's what it seems like is happening from the evidence I have.

Comment: being a relative newbie on the php side, I think I see what you are saying and I think you may be correct. The code for the query is in the same php page that loads the table data. So that kind of explains what you said in your first paragraph. I load the table data by calling including the php file 'query.php' in a table element just above the 'item_hist' div. What is I loaded the table contents with a .load call specifiying the content section to load? ie. .load('query.php #tbl_items'). This would just load the table contents and leave out the query code and content for the history???

Comment: I'm not sure if javascript is excluded when providing a selector with a `load` call.  You can certainly try it.

Comment: I just read the docs, and providing a selector **does** strip out code blocks, so I think that will work.

Comment: However, you will have to change your `click()` call to an `on()` call, or the new table elements will not have their clicks handled at all.

Comment: OK. Let me fiddle for a bit. Thanks so much for your suggestions.

Comment: alright. it looks like simply adding $('.hist-tag').off('click'); before the click function takes care of everything. I'm not sure if this the most efficient way to code what I am hoping to achieve but it seems to work for the most part. If anyone can give me a good reason to change things around, i will be happy to give it a try, otherwise I will accept Lee's solution as the answer...

Comment: Working is always good :).  The disadvantage of that solution is the added overhead of removing handlers and re-adding them for each call.  If the table gets large, the overhead gets bigger.  With the delegated `on` solution (with a selector), you only have a single handler for the entire table.  There is a little more overhead in filtering the clicks, but not as high as removing and adding handlers on each click.

Comment: This solution gets my vote. Alternative is to move the script outside the reloaded div.

Comment: I tried Jeff's solution and it replicates my original problem. I may have misled you, buy my script IS outside of the div "item_hist". However, the script tag is in the query.php page which points to edit.js, where the script is contained.

Comment: You would need to combine this with the `load` with selector as you mentioned above, or else you will add this over and over as well.

Comment: sorry if I am not following correctly, but I am using the exact code that you have above: 
`$('#mytable').on('click', '.hist-tag', function(){
    var ID=$(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
    itemid=$("#itemid_input_"+ID).val();
    dataString = '?rec_id='+ID;
    $('#item_hist').load('query.php' + dataString);
});`

Comment: Sorry, you want to also do `.load('query.php #tbl_items')`, so that the javascript does not run twice.